# Importing the GSON library jar file into my project is not producing expected results

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, gson

Hope you're doing well. I'm creating this simple app where you write text into a TextField and it should write it within a new JSON File in the resources folder. I'm pretty sure that my code is perfectly fine upon checking it with my professors, however, upon importing the library as seen here:

[image]

And executing the following code when the button is pushed:

*I have the following imports at the top of my JFRame class (The IDE shows no errors under those lines) :

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
```

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create(); //<-- The error always comes from this line
```

I get the following error which I have no idea how to fix:

[image]

I have read that switching to a Maven project is an alternative but it's not recommended for my practical. Any solutions would be greatly appreciated. I must also further note that the jar file is located in my libs folder and it is there.

Many thanks!

Edit: They asked me how my program was executed and this is what goes into the compiler in vscode (I execute it in the Run -> Run without Debugging):

```
 c:; cd  'c:\ContentBoxFinalPrac\ContentBox'; & 'c:\Users\ytobi\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.32.1\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-15.0.2.7-hotspot\bin\java.exe' '--enable-preview' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '@C:\Users\ytobi\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_chdymt7vzhi9in94pnpo6ha1h.argfile' 'ui.HomeScreen'
```

Comment: How are you running your program? Did you make sure the jar file is in the classpath there?

Comment: Hi @Andreas, I added what goes into the compiler, hope it helps. I'm not sure how you can if the jar file is in the classpath.

Comment: Why is switching to Maven (or any other alternative like gradle) "not recommended"? I guess anyone would suggest you to build your project with a tool that makes things easier.

Comment: Please post the smallest code snippets that can reproduce your errors.

Comment: @Andreas, I have now made sure that the jar file was in the classpath and the error always comes from this line in the code:  Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

I tried to use a different json library in my project which had been imported correctly, however the compiler always breaks down when it tries to create a new object based on that library

Comment: Can you share the smallest code snippets if convenient? That may be a huge help for solving your question if others can reproduce your question.

Comment: @MollyWang done! :)

Comment: Wow, let's shoot the person down for asking a valid question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed for those still searching. I had to install this SDK which I was missing from VSCode -> Here https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-5.0.202-windows-x64-installer?journey=vs-code

and just create a new project in the left hand bottom panel. Then import everything as you should and demonstrated by Molly Wang.

Answer (score 1):

I download [gson-2.8.6.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6) from Maven Repository, after adding it to referenced libraries, the code works well:

[image]

Please check if your jar misses some parts. Open command palette and choose **Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace** then redownload the jar and see if question goes away.

Comment: Error still appears unfortunately, I tried downloading it from the same place, have no idea what it could be.